# How to run a function for every specific received packet?

Tags: networking, bash, scripts

I am doing an experiment for my master thesis. I want to run a function (e.g. multiply two numbers) when a specific packet is received (e.g. a packet with destination TCP port 6666) and then forward the packet to another IP address.
How can I do it? I'm using Linux Ubuntu. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What applications are you considering to capture and replay the packets? Please add as much detail to your question as possible. As it stands, your question is far too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using linux it's very easy, in linux a packet is represented by structure sk_buff. You can use netfilter framework with pre-routing hook,to mangle packet  by using it's protocol and destnation port number.
 See the netfilter framework documentation .

Comment: Could you include a link, please?